Create subset and calculate sums in Python based on a condition
I am currently doing some data manipulation procedures and have run into a problem of how to make subsets based on special conditions.
My example (dataframe) is like this:
Name    ID      Debt    DurationOfDelay CD
A       ID1     10      15              1
A       ID1     15      30              1
A       ID2     20      60              2
A       ID2     40      60              3
A       ID3     20      15              3
A       ID3     20      60              3

B       ID4     15      30              4
B       ID4     30      60              4
B       ID5     35      40              3
B       ID6     35      0               2
B       ID7     80      30              3
B       ID7     35      60              2

My goal is to create one subset (one new dataframe), where for each unique Name the sum of Debt is returned given a condition:
To take into account IDs with at least two Debts with different DurationOfDelay.
Expected result:
Name    Debt_Delay_15to_30 Debt_Delay_15to_60 Debt_Delay_30to_60 
A       10                 20                 0             
B       0                  0                  95   

Any help is highly appreciated!

Can you provide the exact conditions for the given example?

for current example it seems you need df.groupby(['name', 'DurationOfDelay').sum() and maybe first you should group by IDs, DurationOfDelay and check which group has size > 1 - and get these IDs and filter data before summing.
